How to improve a List Comprehension in python
I'm attempting to convert this function to a List Comprehension but I have to do a work around using set() to prevent False from repeating.
And the locations are not in order. e.g. {0, 12, 5} instead of [0, 5, 12].
Can someone advise where I'm going wrong?
def song_lyrics(a_list, lyric):
    location = []
    for pos, word in enumerate(a_list):
        if word == lyric:
            location.append(pos)
        elif lyric not in a_list:
            return False
    return location

the_wall = 'we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont'.split()
result = song_lyrics(the_wall, 'we')
print(result)

def song_lyrics(a_list, lyric):
    location = set([pos if word == lyric else False for pos, word in enumerate(a_list)])
    return location


You can't do this with a list comprehension. You can't stop the iteration early, and it can't return False instead of a list.

Why is the lyric not in a_list check inside the loop? It doesn't depend on the current element of the loop, so check it first.

Why do you want to return False instea of an empty list when lyric isn't found?

An empty list is a much better idea than False. Switching datatypes depending on the data is going to be a source of bugs after future development.

Small note: why are you using a list comprehension and then turning it into a set, rather than using a set comprehension? Not that a set appears to be necessary.

Requirement is the function returns False if there's no match, not an empty list.  Re. using a list comprehension and then turning it into a set - that's my attempt at a work around. Target word 'nowe' in the function call will produce False for every word in the list.

You can certainly gather up all the indices in a list comprehension/one liner but returning False if it's empty is more naturally done in two lines.
def song_lyrics(a_list, lyric):
    location = [pos for pos, word in enumerate(a_list) if word == lyric]
    return location if location else False # because you want to return False instead of an empty list

the_wall = 'we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont'.split()
r1 = song_lyrics(the_wall, 'nowe')
print(r1) # False
r2 = song_lyrics(the_wall, 'need')
print(r2) # [2,7]


Just return locations or False would be more obvious way (and even can be one line, if necessary). You rarely need x if x else y

Following on @STerliakov comment, you don't even need to name that intermediate location variable. Its a one liner: return [pos for pos, word in enumerate(a_list) if word == lyric] or False

The test for if lyric not in list doesn't need to be in the loop or list comprehension.
To keep False from being included in the list, use a filter in the comprehension rather than a conditional expression.
location = lyric in a_list and [pos for pos, word in enumerate(a_list) if word == lyric]


def find_indexes(text, lyric):
    words = text.split()
    result = [index for index, word in enumerate(words) if word == lyric]
    result = result if len(result) > 0 else False
    return result

the_wall = 'we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont'
print(find_indexes(the_wall, 'nowe'))
# Result: False
print(find_indexes(the_wall, 'we'))
# Result: [0, 5, 12]


Your code doesn't return False if the word isn't found. And why have you changed the lyric parameter to a hard-coded value?

You are right @Barmar. I edited my answer. Although I see more benefits from returning an empty list.

Thanks guys. Appreciate all the comments and the coding, learnt a few things. Tks a lot :)
